# Laravel JSON-API, includes are not consistent when a model is included multiple times

Tags: laravel, json-api

We have stumbled across a bug that I can only assume is a bug with the JSON API code. This is for the old laravel JSON API (in my composer.json file its `"cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api": "^2.0"`)

The issue is when a resource is included multiple times (in different ways), it is possible to not get all the include information you asked for.

In my example, I am dealing with timesheets. Timesheets belong to a user. They are also approved by a user. Those users are usually different users, but not always. If I want to include both, I would add `include=user,approved-by`, and this works great.

The front end also sometimes needs to know the employeeType of the user, so we instead use `include=user.employee-type,approved-by`, and again this works, we get the employee type info for the user. The issue arises when the user is the same as the approver. It appears that JSON-API gets the approved-by user (without the employee type include data), then when it tries to get the timesheet user, it sees that is has already grabbed that user, and just stops there.

The difference in the output is:
The include with the related in

```
"employeeType": {
  "data": {
    "type": "employee-types",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "link url",
    "related": "link url"
  }
},
```

Vs the include without all the related info

```
"employeeType": {
  "links": {
    "self": "link url",
    "related": "link url"
  }
},
```

We have a work around, where we need to include the employee type of the user and a the approver, but that seems cumbersome and annoying.

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is any good fix for this? Or if this has been fixed in the more recent version (could be the kick in the pants we need to actually migrate to the most recent version of the library)

Comment: Did you reported this bug to the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api)? I guess a reproduction would be very helpful. Also to verify if it is fixed in recent versions.
What is the impact of it? Is it resulting in an invalid JSON:API document, which does not have full linkage for all included resources? Or are the `employee-types` not included at all?

Comment: Good point, this probably belongs on the github page instead (though I am not sure they are supporting the old version anymore).

The impact is an invalid JSON:API document. The employee type is included, however on the user resource there is no indication of what employee type it is linked to